# K-means clustering on point cloud data how to get the cluster number each point belongs to

Tags: c++, k-means, point-cloud-library

I am interested in doing kmeans analysis on point cloud data. I wish to know how to obtain the cluster number for each point belongs to following the kmeans analysis. I have read the similar thread titled "K-means clustering on point cloud data" however I have thus far been unable to determine how to obtain the cluster number data using the "pcl::Kmeans::ClustersToPoints" function.

```
std::string filePath = "/path/to/pointcloud/Fruit_bunch2.pcd";

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tempCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

std::cout << "Reading file" << std::endl;

    if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile(filePath, *tempCloud) == -1) //* load the file
    {
        printf("failed file load!\n");}
    else
    {

        std::cout << "Calculating Kmeans" << std::endl;

        pcl::Kmeans mykmeans (tempCloud->points.size(), 3);
        mykmeans.setClusterSize(3);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < tempCloud->points.size(); i++)
            {
                std::vector<float> data(3);
                data[0] = tempCloud->points[i].x;
                data[1] = tempCloud->points[i].y;
                data[2] = tempCloud->points[i].z;
                mykmeans.addDataPoint(data);
            }

        mykmeans.kMeans();

        // Get the cluster centroids
        pcl::Kmeans::Centroids centroids = mykmeans.get_centroids();
        std::cout << "Points in total Cloud : " << tempCloud->points.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Centroid count: " << centroids.size() << std::endl;

            for (int i = 0; i < centroids.size(); i++)
            {
                std::cout << " Centroid " << i << " output: x: " << centroids[i][0] << " ,";
                std::cout << "y: " << centroids[i][1] << " ,";
                std::cout << "z: " << centroids[i][2] << std::endl;
            }

        pcl::Kmeans::ClustersToPoints myClusters;
        //How do I get the cluster that each point belongs to ?

    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the API for `pcl::Kmeans`?

Comment: I just checked and I don't see a function in the API for getting the clusters. I'm not sure I would use this library. The documentation seems terrible and the source code has whole functions commented out.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have had a read through the pcl::Kmeans documentation and come to a similar conclusion. Maybe the easier route is to use a library that is better written and documented . Thanks for taking the time to look into this